# Qt hello world example does not display anything on LCD

Tags: c++, qt

I have colibri evaluation board 3.1a with Tegra 2 on it. I have compiled Qt library and copied to board. I was trying simple hello world button app.
Program runs fine(confirmed by inserting prints), but i dont get anything on the LCD display.

This is the simple code i am trying

```
QApplication a( argc, argv );

QPushButton hello( "Hello world!", 0 );
hello.resize( 100, 30 );

a.setMainWidget( &hello );
hello.show();
return a.exec();
```

Comment: Probably a sysadmin issue, not a programming one. What operating system is running on your board?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Thanks for the reply. I am running linux

Comment: Are you using Qt Embedded? Did you test any other GUI app?

Comment: @svlasov. Thanks for the reply. yes I am using Qt embedded. I have also tried test examples(i.e /usr/local/Qtembedded/tests/).

Comment: Did you try the official toolchain? http://developer.toradex.com/how-to/how-to-set-up-qt-creator-to-cross-compile-for-embedded-linux Also, are you sure you connected the LCD properly?

Comment: @svlasov. Yes i have used toradex toolchain. I have connected LCD properly. I am getting Linux GUI on LCD.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use `-qws` flag:

```
./myapp -qws
```

Comment: You don't really need `a.setMainWidget( &hello );`, try to remove it.

Comment: removed. Nothing yet. I simply copied code from net to test Qt. I am new to Qt. I even tried test examples.

Comment: One more thought. Try to set `QWS_DISPLAY="LinuxFb:/dev/fb:genericcolors"` before running the app.